# Angular Two different layouts in same app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS for a store app(using Laravel for back-end as API). But now I want to implement a blog on the same app. For example I'm in the store(this has one layout), I click on the Blog link in the menu and it redirects me to another page that has a totally different layout. Is this possible?

Here is my index.html:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/#/"><i class="ion-ios7-pulse-strong"></i> Ugurt</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-if="isAuthenticated()"><a href="/#/post">Post</a></li>
        <li ng-if="isAuthenticated()"><a href="/#/blog">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="/#/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="/#/logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Different Partial Files -->
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my `stateProvider` config(a portion):

```
angular.module('Ugurt', ['ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', 'toastr', 'ui.router', 'satellizer', 'checklist-model', 'ngCart', 'textAngular'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
  })
  .state('store', {
    url: '/store',
    controller: 'StoreCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/store.html'
  })
```

Every link I click on shows a different partial file because of the `ui-view` attribute. But when I click on the Blog link, I want it to lead to a different file that a completely different layout and menu. 
I want to put the both in the same app because the register and login is going to be the same for both parts. And when one user is logged in in the store, if he goes to the Blog part, I still want him to be logged in without doing anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it's possible to do. You must config the router to work like so. Do you have any `$stateProvider` configuration?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my question.

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ui-router like structure, you have route names, so you just need to create new route with different layout and redirect to new route.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are already a way to do that, using a proper router like [`ui-router`](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router).

For example:

You have two main states, store and blog. What you can do is configure those two states in te `$stateProvider` under `app.config`.

For example:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('store', {
        url: '/store',
        templateUrl: 'store-layout.html'
    });

    // and then, when it requires to have substate of store you must inherit this state from store state
    // also you'll have to specify a new ui-view inside store-layout.html to be the outlet of the nested states

    $stateProvider.state('store.categories', {
        url: '/store/categories',
        templateUrl: 'store-categories.html'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('blog', {
        url: '/blog',
        templateUrl: 'blog-layout.html'
    });

    $stateProvider.otherwise('/store');
});
```